# Add git to existing project on server

Tags: git, server

I know maybe this question is answered somewhere but I didn't find a solution for it.  I have a project that is already in a live server  and I want to add a .git to be able to pull/push from my local machine.

I was thinking that I can do on the server : 
git init
git remote add origin git@project.git
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"

But it seems not to be the right way so I tried  to do a git init --bare project.git and clone from my local, but the directory is empty.

Can someone tell me how I can do add git in this case.
Thank You.

Comment: A bare repo can't have a worktree (otherwise it's not bare anymore), i.e. you can't push to a repo that has a checked out worktree. (I hope I understood you correctly)

Comment: Thanks Henri, so can you tell me how I can do to add git in a project that is already in a live server?

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you want to do and I have done the same thing before.  What I wanted was something like this, where both folders are Git repos

```
  laptop              server
~/website   <=>   /var/www/html
  .git/             .git/
  index.html        index.html
```

However, that is not possible because from my laptop I can't push to the repo in `/var/www/html` because that is not a bare repo.  I also can't make it a bare repo because a bare repo doesn't have a worktree (which I need because that's the files that display my website).

So instead I needed a middle man:

```
  laptop            server              server
~/website   <=>   website.git   =>   /var/www/html
  .git/                                .git/
  index.html                           index.html
```

where `website.git` is a bare repo.  Then I just add a post receive hook in the file `website.git/hooks/post-receive` that `cd`s to `/var/www/html` and pulls from the bare repo that's on the same hard drive.  Here is my hook

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# unset environment set by git
unset $(git rev-parse --local-env-vars)

# go to website and assemble
cd /var/www/html
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master

# Whatever other instruction you need to build the website
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation but I just want to put my project that is on a live server in GitHub.  Maybe a have to use FTP download the project  and setup git and them login ssh on the server and pull? I don't know